# Delay in Tumbleweed Badge

Tags: discussion, badges, tumbleweed-badge

Came across this question [from July 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258721/accessing-http-request-before-sending-to-server) which was awarded Tumbleweed [only 16 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=393101).

I'm wondering what sequence of events could cause this to be thus delayed unless it's a bug?

Comment: I had [the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227136/how-can-you-graphically-represent-the-number-of-authors-per-page-in-mediawiki). No idea what the reason is.

Comment: @Wikis Commit At Area 51 : Tumbleweed is only awarded once. Even if your first eligible post got deleted, the system would have recalculated it for the 2nd one and seen you've already been awarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up until 17 hours ago there was an answer to the question, which makes it invalid for the Tumbleweed badge.

Then the answer was deleted by Bill the Lizard, which makes it eligible again since apparently the Tumblweed badge doesn't count deleted answers.

Comment: Ah, is that something you see as a 10K user - which erm, I don't.

Comment: @Jose, yep. 10k users can see deleted posts.