# Is it time to recalculate some badges and revoke ones that no longer are valid?

Tags: discussion, badges

Due to the ongoing migration of posts to prog.se, some people would have badges which are no longer valid on SO.

Example - my profile has a Silver `Good answer` badge which moved to prog.se, so when you click on the badge [it seems broken](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/24/good-answer?userid=289396)

```
(post deleted or otherwise unavailable)
```

I know badges will get calculated at the next point of awarding, but if lots of questions are getting deleted or migrated, is now a good time for a one-off recalc on certain badges like those awarded multiple times to Good/Nice Questions/Answers/Comments?

Another example is [this guy's Tumbleweed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84314/delay-in-tumbleweed-badge) I posed a question about earlier.

I dont think this will affect the league toppers ([Pascal's been missing for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent?tab=activity#apage_2-afilter_all), but earns badges each week), but will clean up a majority of those in the middle and bottom.

Comment: Are you suggesting that badges should be migrated with questions?

Comment: @Gabe: Yes that could do. I think when the algorithm runs on the migrated site, you do get a new badge, but the old one remains.

Comment: This would make `Electorate` even that much harder to maintain.  My first months worth of spamming nothing but question votes and no answer upvotes would be all for naught :(  I do, however, think anyone's `Fanatic` badge should be revoked when they no longer have a current streak of 100+ days going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Stack Exchange generally does not revoke badges, even if the reason no longer exists. What happens when another badge is awarded is not that badges are recalculated, but that badge counts are recalculated. When a badge is actually revoked (usually due to a programming error), the badge count in your profile and on your user card (the little box at the end of every post you make) gets out of sync. That number is fixed the next time a badge is awarded, but badges themselves are not cancelled.

Comment: yes, i knew that - my suggestion is to actually do a one-off cleanup and *revoke* those badges. that's the word I was looking for.