# How can this user have earned 221 reputation without it showing up in their profile?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

How come this user ([user428916](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428916/user428916?tab=stats)) has 221 reputation? [At the time of this writing]

He has asked 7 questions, of which, only 2 received upvotes, giving him 10 reputation. For answers, he has only one that has been upvoted, which is only another 10 reputation. And since everyone starts out with 1 reputation, his total becomes 21. And since he doesn't have accounts on any other Stack Exchange site that he's associated, he didn't get the +100 rep bonus.

So why does it show him has having 221? These numbers don't add up!

Also he was awarded "Nice Answer" badge, but I can't tell for what. He doesn't have any answer with more than 10 upvotes. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps he's had questions/answers deleted and not had a reputation recalculation recently.

Comment: @ChrisF: deleted questions/answers containing 200 reputations?....:-\

Comment: Is it really worth asking? :D

Comment: Possibly - I'm not a mod on SO so I can't see if there are any.

Comment: If you click the ['nice answer' badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=428916) then it shows you it's for [this question 'removed for reasons of moderation'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900727/using-classes-in-c/5903117#5903117). So he's got at least 100 from a deleted answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900727/using-classes-in-c/5903117#5903117

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ChrisF's theory is correct. The user posted [this joke answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900727/using-classes-in-c/5903117#5903117) to a question:

> You should try to create a GUI interface with Visual Basic to track the IP address...

which *somehow*<sup>*</sup> earned him 20 upvotes (+200 rep) and a "Nice Answer" badge.

The answer was deleted by a moderator about 2 hours after it was posted (presumably as a result of a flag or multiple flags), and then a few days later, the entire question was deleted after 4 different users (including one moderator) cast a deletion vote.

So in summary, the user hasn't performed a reputation recalc recently, and there hasn't been one imposed site-wide since the question/answer were deleted. That's why his reputation is much inflated. And since [badges are never revoked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87545/is-it-time-to-recalculate-some-badges-and-revoke-ones-that-no-longer-are-valid/87546#87546), he still has the "Nice Answer" badge for an answer that...wasn't really all that nice.

<sup>* The "somehow" is that the question was [redditted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit). That's a quick way to boost vote counts to unexpected and unreasonable levels, and also to attract the attention of a very different crowd than the typical SO user, willing to vote answers like this *up*, rather than *down*.</sup>

Comment: after recalculation what will happen to badge?

Comment: @Harry: Nothing. Badges don't get revoked, even after recalculations. They have to be manually removed by a moderator. Under normal circumstances, that won't happen. However, if they earn that badge again for something else, it won't actually be awarded again.

Comment: about the joke: [GUI interface using visual basic to track the killers IP address CSI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU)

Comment: Yup, I watched that episode on an actual TV (ZOMG!). Saw it first-hand. It was quite funny at the time, but repeating it as an answer just zaps any humor value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the answer that earned him the Nice Answer badge (100-240 rep) was deleted and there hasn't been a recalc done. When a post is deleted the rep stays until there has been a recalc.

It's also possible that there is an account association that you can't see (when I made a post here, where my account was associated with my StackOverflow account and I had received the +100 bonus, somebody said that that all they could see was a stand alone meta account).

Comment: The account association bonus is only possible if he has unassociated the account in the mean time.

Comment: True 20 votes on the nice answer badge is more likely but it is possible.